# How to Evaluate the index of a list while keep the list Unevaluated?

Tags: evaluation

I have the following simple example:

```
letter= {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
idx=1; (*just for example*)
ToString[Unevaluated[letter[[idx]]]]
```

> the output is `letter[[idx]]`, which is expected.

**Question**: I wonder and am curious that how one can get **the output is** `letter[[1]]` where `idx` is evaluated while `letter[[1]]` not (I would like this works for all index in `letter`)

Well, I thought `Unevaluated[letter[[Evaluate[idx]]]]`, but this for sure will not solve my question. I don't know whether it is possible to solve it. Any comments or suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ToString[Unevaluated[letter[[#]]]] &@idx
```

> ```
>  "letter[[1]]"
> ```

Also

```
With[{idx = idx}, ToString[Unevaluated[letter[[idx]]]]]
```

> ```
> "letter[[1]]"
> ```

and

```
ToString[Unevaluated@letter[[idx]]] // StringReplace["idx" -> ToString[idx]]
```

> ```
>  "letter[[1]]"
> ```

Comment: cool, thank you! didn't expect so simple, thank you so much!

Comment: @XuemeiGu, you are most welcome.

Comment: @XuemeiGu did you mean to ask for a string output, or that of an expression? If the latter, the second of kglr’s forms is well suited. One might try the following input, everything else considered: `With[{idx=idx}, Defer[ letter[[idx]] ] ]` which should give you `letter[[1]]`.

Comment: @CATrevillian, I think for an expression and only part is evaluated. `Defer` function is nice, I don't know such function. Thank you!

Comment: @XuemeiGu No problem! I’m sure kglr can show a better or equivalent way of using such a function, but I use it with some rather questionable combinations of `Evaluate` and `Unevaluated` to pull arguments from an expression inputted into a function that uses the results of the expression along with the arguments inputted into the expression, so it can be pretty versatile when you want it to be!